# How can I make it so that the file opens when i click it

Tags: python, pygtk

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')

import gtk

# Check for new pygtk: this is new class in PyGtk 2.4
if gtk.pygtk_version < (2,3,90):
   print "PyGtk 2.3.90 or later required for this example"
   raise SystemExit

dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open..",
                               None,
                               gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                               (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
dialog.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)

filter = gtk.FileFilter()
filter.set_name("All files")
filter.add_pattern("*")
dialog.add_filter(filter)

filter = gtk.FileFilter()
filter.set_name("Images")
filter.add_mime_type("image/png")
filter.add_mime_type("image/jpeg")
filter.add_mime_type("image/gif")
filter.add_pattern("*.png")
filter.add_pattern("*.jpg")
filter.add_pattern("*.gif")
filter.add_pattern("*.tif")
filter.add_pattern("*.xpm")
dialog.add_filter(filter)

response = dialog.run()
if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
    print dialog.get_filename(), 'selected'
elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
    print 'Closed, no files selected'
dialog.destroy()
```

Comment: `open(dialog.get_filename())`?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"?  You want to open it in whatever program the user has associated with that file extension?  Or you want to open it in Python and manipulate programmatically?

Comment: open the file in terminal in vi

Answer (score 0):

This is of course for Linux only:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/terminal','-x','/usr/bin/vim', dialog.get_filename()])
```